# Python Function Errors

Tags: python

I know this is not hard, but I keep getting either an undefined error or different errors, I tried everything I could think of to get the solution. I placed the input variables outside of the code and it worked partially. I'm only 3 weeks or so into my first computer science class. help is appreciated, please & thanks.

```
# function that prompts the user for a name and returns it

def user():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    return name

# function that receives the user's name as a parameter, and prompts the user for an age and returns it

def userAge(name):
    age = input("How old are you, {}? ".format(name))
    return age
# function that receives the user's name and age as parameters and displays the final output

def finalOutput(name, age):
    age2x = int(age) * 2
    print("Hi, {}.  You are {} years old.  Twice your age is {}.").format(name, age, str(age2x))

###############################################
# MAIN PART OF THE PROGRAM
# implement the main part of your program below
# comments have been added to assist you
###############################################
# get the user's name

user()

# get the user's age

userAge("name")

# display the final output

finalOutput("name", "age")
```

Comment: If you have errors then include the full stacktrace from those errors, also you're not capturing the return values from your functions so they simply disappear into the ether

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what fixes have you tried so far and what **specifically** is going wrong? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You're not storing the values the user supplies, or passing them back to your function calls, here:

```
user()
userAge("name")
finalOutput("name", "age")
```

Change the above lines to:

```
name = user()
age = userAge(name)
finalOutput(name,age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction 1:

Don't pass arguments with **double quotes**, that means you are passing a string literal to the function not actual value of variable.
for example, if you assign variable name as "Jhon" and you pass it to the function as userAge("name") means you are passing string literal "name" to userAge() not variable value "Jhon".

```
def printName(name):
    print(name)
name = "jhon"
printName("name")
```

output: name

```
def printName(name):
    print(name)
name = "jhon"
printName(name)
```

output: jhon

Better assign the return value to some Valerie and pass without double quotes as mentioned by @TBurgis.

Correction 2:

Syntax mistake in print statement. Correct syntax should be

```
print("Hi, {}.  You are {} years old.  Twice your age is {}.".format(name, age, str(age2x)))
```